# Remove pop sounds in mic recording in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way in realtime to smoothen the pop sounds a bad microphone makes when recording?

We have a voice chat feature, and those who don't have a pop filter or wind screen on their microphone create this unwanted noise at times upon letters like **"t"** or **"p"**.

We're using common Unity functions like `Microphone.Start()` and `recordedAudio.GetData()` and such to then send those over the wire. Thanks!

Comment: When making a voice chat in Unity, do not use Unity's built in Microphone API. Go native. You have write a recording code for each platform. C++ for Windows API, Java for Android and Object-C for iOS. You can do a simple research for each of these and you'll see which API to use. Your C# code will then put them together.

Comment: you can try using a highpass filter to cut off frequencies below 150hz.  I know that unity has filters for audio sources but not sure if it can be applied in real time to a mic.. you'll have to investigate that.

Comment: Thanks you two! Will investigate the highpass filter.